# python3 call fread of ctypes cannot get data

Tags: python-3.x, file, ctypes, fread

Python use ctypes API to call c code. Following code works in Python2, but does not work in Python3.8 . I found result of func libc.fread(that is bytes_read) is 0(but actually should be 282624). Anyone know the root cause?

```
real_size = 282624
buffer = (ctypes.c_ubyte * real_size)()
length = real_size

libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library("c"))

# open file
libc.fopen.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
libc.fopen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p)
fp = libc.fopen(file_path, 'rb')
if fp is None:
    raise OSError('Cannot open file {}'.format(file_path))

libc.fclose.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)

# seek offset
libc.fseek.restype = ctypes.c_int
libc.fseek.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_int)
if libc.fseek(fp, 0, os.SEEK_SET) != 0:
    libc.fclose(fp)
    raise IOError("fseek to {} failed".format(file_offset))

libc.fread.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_void_p)
libc.fread.restype = ctypes.c_size_t
bytes_read = libc.fread(ctypes.addressof(buffer), 1, length, fp) #why bytes_read is 0?
```

Or another question is how to use fread to read data from binary file?

Comment: Why not just use Python to read the file?  It's much more straightforward.

Comment: Also what does "does not work" mean?  What error do you get?  Post the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctypes.util.find_library('c')` doesn't work on Windows, but given a C runtime library (I hardcoded one), this works:

```py
from __future__ import print_function  # so this code will work on Python 2 as well
import os
import ctypes as ct

# Opaque type so you can't pass any old void*.
# Better type-safety.
class FILE(ct.Structure):
    pass

# represents FILE* from C
PFILE = ct.POINTER(FILE)

libc = ct.CDLL('msvcrt')
libc.fopen.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, ct.c_char_p
libc.fopen.restype = PFILE
libc.fclose.argtypes = PFILE,
libc.fclose.restype = ct.c_int
libc.fseek.argtypes = PFILE, ct.c_long, ct.c_int
libc.fseek.restype = ct.c_int
libc.fread.argtypes = ct.c_void_p, ct.c_size_t, ct.c_size_t, PFILE
libc.fread.restype = ct.c_size_t

buffer = (ct.c_ubyte * real_size)()

fp = libc.fopen(b'test.bin', b'rb') # Use byte strings for char*
if fp is None:
    raise OSError('Cannot open file {}'.format(file_path))

# Not really needed since file starts at offset 0
if libc.fseek(fp, 0, os.SEEK_SET) != 0:
    libc.fclose(fp)
    raise IOError("fseek to {} failed".format(file_offset))

bytes_read = libc.fread(buffer, 1, length, fp)
print(bytes_read)
```

But then again, so does this without `ctypes`:

```py
with open('test.bin','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
print(len(data))
```

Comment: This code only run in Linux not windows.

Comment: @taotao I have Windows.  Same code, just change the `libc = ct.CDLL(library)` to a Linux C library, or just use the Python code at the bottom.  It calls all the same C library calls "under the covers" and is much simpler.  The line you have for the C library might even work I just don't have a Linux system to test on.  You never said what actually "didn't work" in your code.

Comment: Thank you!  I found result of func libc.fread(that is bytes_read) is 0(but actually should be 282624). That is i do not get any data by API fread.

Comment: Any why i use ctypes not python api, because i need to get fix size of a buffer not all of this buffer.

Comment: I test on my linux env with your code, still get bytes_read is 0.

Comment: @taotao You can read a fixed size with Python too.  `seek` to the offset, `read(n)` the number of bytes you want.  Are you sure the file you are reading has something in it?  You should get an error code or something.  This code works fine, but I'd use Python.  Doing this in ctypes is the wrong solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right i will try to use python API not ctypes.

Comment: And i can read correct data with your code now. I need to find the root cause why my original code cannot work (bytes_read is 0).

Comment: I found use ctypes api to read/write file is much faster than directly by python api.

Comment: I highly doubt that since the Python API calls these same APIs under the covers without the `ctypes` overhead.